# Wait for condition to satisfy for unlimited time in a function :: condition applied on specific value which change frequently (Flutter , Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

This function should remain in waiting for the state until the condition met with no time constraint, and the function should not end up if the condition not met instead it should wait for almost unlimited time

Note :: I am getting ax value changed frequently , on a particular value of ax only i want to execute function

```
MyFunc(){
if(<some condition> ){
   <Code execution>
 }
} 

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'abc',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String? title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    late double ax;
    
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // create this only once
    
        accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
          setState(() {
            ax = event.x;
          });
        });
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title!),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Center(
                child: CircularCountDownTimer(
                 onStart: () {
                  // Here, do whatever you want
                  print('Countdown Started');
                },
                 onComplete: () {
                  // Here, do whatever you want
                  MyFunc();
                }
                 )
    );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Timer Class. [Docs Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html)

```
late Timer backgroundFunction; // the Timer which will keep running until some cond is meet.

bool shouldStop = false;   // Add some variable to know , when to stop

@override
  void initState() {
    
     backgroundFunction = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        shouldStopTImer(); // This will check whether to stop or go on. Every 1 sec 
    });
  }

void shouldStopTImer(){
   if(shouldStop){
     backgroundFunction.cancel();
    }
}


Some logic .......

shoudlStop = true; //When you want to stop. Make it true
```